# How to modify type property in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

here's my problem. I have this code:

```
class Person: NSObject {
private var name: String
var age: Int
class var headsNumber: Int {
    get{
        return Person.headsNumber
    }
    set{
        Person.headsNumber = newValue
    }
}
init(name: String, age: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
}
```

Then, I do:

```
var p = Person(name: "Billy", age: 20)
Person.headsNumber = 2
```

And I get an error when I want to modify the value of headsNumber. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

By implementing `get` and `set` you have made this property computed (the variable is not stored). `Person.headsNumber = 2` starts a loop because you are again setting new value for `headsNumber` in the setter method.

If you simply want to store `headsNumber` you must remove `get` and `set` implementations.